# How to make webpack 4 compile sass only if a sass file has changed, and js only if a js file has changed?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I'm using webpack to compile my sass into css and to transpile my js. The problem I'm facing is when I'm using webpack-dev-server and I make a change to my sass files, the js recompiles too, this can take some time depending on how much js I have, so I would like to know if it's possible to make webpack 4 only recompile the css and not js, or if it must compile both, how do I make it output my css first and then work on the js?

[webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/opr/3ceaad044bf69ad7f789aa979df7333c)

Comment: Can you add your webpack configuration file? We can suggest some loaders/plugins configurations that use cache/more processes. Also -> I'm not sure it's possible (or even a good idea). if one file has changed, it may (or even probably) effects other files.

Comment: added! The thing is, we had this working fine with gulp. When the sass files change, only the CSS output changes nothing else. We wanted to move away from gulp to webpack only (we were using gulp to run webpack, which seemed wrong) but it appears that we're losing functionality by doing this.